# Prepare bind a blank value (not a null value)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, notnull

I need to insert a blank (`foo=""`) into my database, but when I do:

```
bindParam(':foo','',PDO::PARAM_STR);
bindParam(':bar','bang',PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

And look at the table, `bar`=`bang`, but `foo` is null. I want it to be  (blank, not a space) not `null`.

(I need to do this because the data will be exported to SPSS, and blank is SPSS's `null`)

I've looked thru [php.net/…/pdo.constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) and the rest of the manual, and I only see instances of blanks getting inserted because of a weird alignment of Venus during an eclipse on the third blue moon.

**EDIT**: php 5.3, mysql 5.1 (and I dunno the driver version)

Comment: What about making your column `NOT NULL`?

Comment: The short answer is I sometimes need a column to be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

PDO should be inserting the empty string (check your database directly to confirm this).  However, I think PDO will coerce the empty string to NULL when *fetching* data, unless you tell it not to.

Try this on your PDO handle:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL);
```

Comment: I did look directly in my Db/table, and it says NULL. I'm inserting/updating _not fetching_. Does your suggestion still apply?

Comment: It's probably still worth a shot.  Mentioning your PHP, DB, and DB driver versions in your question may also be helpful.

Comment: php 5.3, mysql 5.1, and i don't know the driver version

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using bindvalue?

```
bindValue( ':foo', '', PDO::PARAM_STR );
bindValue( ':bar', 'bang', PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

Comment: you're not using `PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING` are you?